# Reuse Office365 logon session in a Word macro

Tags: vba, microsoft-graph-api, office365, sharepoint-online

I have an Office 365 subscription at work. When I go to the Account screen in MS Word, it shows my corporate identity. So behind the scenes, there is an active logon session with the Microsoft Graph API.

Can I tap into that login session from a VBA macro (e. g. retrieve a logon token)?  I'd like to create a list item in a Sharepoint Online list without making the user go through the logon flow.

Comment: Looks like you can't *directly*, but [it seems possible](https://www.devhut.net/2020/10/07/vba-determine-microsoft-office-logged-in-user-account/) via WMI and registry queries (this gets the display name; getting the actual token is probably something else, if possible at all)

Comment: Funny thing though, when I navigate to the Graph logon page in a Web browser control in a macro, it doesn't even display a UI - goes straight to the callback URL with a code that can be exchanged for a token. Not sure, though, if it reuses the Office session or the Windows session. Either way, this is workable.

Comment: It should work as per the papers, but keep in mind that VBA/macros are not designed to work as interactive logins (atleast as far as i know when i played with Outlook macro's which requires user should exist). I am not sure it's same issue happening here too, which looks for identity/credentials and stuck with the user credential prompt.